# ALB Ingress Kubernetes security group annotation is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using an existing Security Group in `security-groups` annotation. But while creating ALB through Ingress it is attaching a default SG. Why it is not attaching the existing SG used in my annotation. And I am using `alb-ingress-controller`.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: "instance"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-**********
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80,"HTTPS": 443}]'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: host
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: serviceName
          servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

the actual syntax for annotation is 
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-xxxx, nameOfSg1, nameOfSg2

You need to create a pair of SGs. One attaching to ELB and other one attaching to worker nodes where the pods are running.

if sg-12345 with Name tag 'elb_sg' is attaching to ELB and 'worker_sg' is attaching to worker nodes, then the annotation should be:
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-12345, elb_sg, worker_sg

And dont forget to add inbound on worker_sg to all traffic from elb_sg.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having no issue with specifying an existing Security Group through 'security-groups' annotation (works w/o any problem with aws-alb-ingress-controller in v1.1.2, which one you use ?).

Do you see any errors in alb-ingress controller's Pod while creating new Ingress resource ?

You can check it with following command*:

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | egrep -o alb-ingress[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
```

* might differ a bit in your case, depending on which namespace alb-ingress was deployed into.